# Unable to define a variable error - html,css,js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gsap

I am facing a bit of difficulty with defining the `MotionPathPlugin` as it says `variable not defined`

Before, it said `gsap not defined` and I managed to fix that by adding

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.min.js"></script>`

However, I am unable to fix this error:

[image]

The code works perfectly fine on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pfeilal23/pen/wvKdmJr) but it is not working on `repl.it` for some reason. I will paste my code of the animation here too, in case there is a particular reference I may be missing. I added that particular line to avoid the error `gsap not defined` but I cannot seem to figure out the solution to this error. Any suggestions?

The error occurs here on StackOverFlow too:

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

const tween = gsap.timeline();
tween.to(".paper-plane", {
  duration: 1,
  ease: "power1.inOut",
  motionPath: {
    path: [
        {x: 100, y: 0},
        {x: 300, y: 10},
        {x: 500, y: 100},
        {x: 750, y: -100},
        {x: 350, y: -50},
        {x: 600, y: 100},
        {x: 800, y: 0},
        {x: window.innerWidth, y: -250}
    ], 
    curviness: 2,
    autoRotate: true
  }
});

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: '.animation',
duration: 1000,
triggerHook: 0
})
.setTween(tween)
.setPin('.animation')
.addTo(controller);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header, footer{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
header h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}
.animation{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.paper-plane{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation">
        <img class="paper-plane" src="https://i.postimg.cc/W1w9dT1x/paper.png" alt="Paper Plane">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a bunch of libraries. You need:

- [ScrollMagic](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js) (make sure to load this first)
- [ScrollMagic's animation plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js)
- The [MotionPathPlugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/MotionPathPlugin.min.js)

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

const tween = gsap.timeline();
tween.to(".paper-plane", {
  duration: 1,
  ease: "power1.inOut",
  motionPath: {
    path: [
        {x: 100, y: 0},
        {x: 300, y: 10},
        {x: 500, y: 100},
        {x: 750, y: -100},
        {x: 350, y: -50},
        {x: 600, y: 100},
        {x: 800, y: 0},
        {x: window.innerWidth, y: -250}
    ], 
    curviness: 2,
    autoRotate: true
  }
});

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: '.animation',
duration: 1000,
triggerHook: 0
})
.setTween(tween)
.setPin('.animation')
.addTo(controller);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header, footer{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
header h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}
.animation{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.paper-plane{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation">
        <img class="paper-plane" src="https://i.postimg.cc/W1w9dT1x/paper.png" alt="Paper Plane">
    </div>
```

Comment: It still does not work for me, I am getting this error: `GSAP target .paper-plane not found. https://greensock.com`

Comment: Works fine here - press "Run code snippet" to see it working once those libraries are included.

Comment: Bt on `repl.it` it says that error, do you know what can fix that?

Comment: If it's not working there, then you probably aren't including all the required libraries. Look at the HTML markup in my answer.

Comment: I copied the html code u provided but it still does not work

Comment: I just created a standalone file from the HTML, JS, and CSS in the answer and it worked fine there too. If the code isn't working for you, it sounds like you didn't copy it correctly.

Comment: Here is the link to my IDE: https://repl.it/join/funomnxh-hussainomer

Comment: That link appears to require me to register to something in order to see anything... regardless, I'm sure the code works, it's displaying the animated paper plane fine in both the Stack Snippet and in a standalone file.

Comment: Okay nevermind, I have fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.