# Scroll Line Animation - HTML,CSS,JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to output the letter `H` using the SVG Line Animation and I am stuck at one part, I am not sure where to edit/modify the elements so it outputs the Letter `H`. I want to output this image by `SVG Drawing On Scroll`:

[image]

It seems a bit too complicated and my attempt at first was to modify the `<path` elements but I got a different unexpected output. I used the `SVG Drawing On Scroll` template from codepen, and I would like to modify to output the image above **on scroll**. I was wondering if I could get some assistance on this. Any suggestions?

Code of the template:

```js
// Get a reference to the <path>
var path = document.querySelector('#star-path');

// Get length of path... ~577px in this case
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

// Make very long dashes (the length of the path itself)
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;

// Offset the dashes so the it appears hidden entirely
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

// Jake Archibald says so
// https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
path.getBoundingClientRect();

// When the page scrolls...
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
 
  // What % down is it? 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript/2387222#2387222
  // Had to try three or four differnet methods here. Kind of a cross-browser nightmare.
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    
  // Length to offset the dashes
  var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
  
  // Draw in reverse
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    
  // When complete, remove the dash array, otherwise shape isn't quite sharp
 // Accounts for fuzzy math
  if (scrollPercentage >= 0.99) {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "none";
    
  } else {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  /* feel free to change height */
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    orange,
    darkblue
  );
}

h1 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

#star-svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}



Resources
```

```html
<h1>Scroll-to-draw</h1>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100.6 107.6" id="star-svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="star-path" d="M43.7,65.8L19.9,83.3c-2.9,1.9-5.1,3.2-7.9,3.2c-5.7,0-10.5-5.1-10.5-10.8
    c0-4.8,3.8-8.2,7.3-9.8l27.9-12L8.8,41.4c-3.8-1.6-7.3-5.1-7.3-9.8c0-5.7,5.1-10.5,10.8-10.5c2.9,0,4.8,1,7.6,3.2l23.8,17.4
    l-3.2-28.2c-1-6.7,3.5-12,9.8-12c6.3,0,10.8,5.1,9.8,11.7L57,41.8l23.8-17.4c2.9-2.2,5.1-3.2,7.9-3.2c5.7,0,10.5,4.8,10.5,10.5
    c0,5.1-3.5,8.2-7.3,9.8L63.9,53.8l27.9,12c3.8,1.6,7.3,5.1,7.3,10.1c0,5.7-5.1,10.5-10.8,10.5c-2.5,0-4.8-1.3-7.6-3.2L57,65.8
    l3.2,28.2c1,6.7-3.5,12-9.8,12c-6.3,0-10.8-5.1-9.8-11.7L43.7,65.8z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This would only work if your svg is composed of a single path as well. Can you share your svg file?

Comment: Thats all there is, I do not have any SVG file.

Comment: It's generally considered to be extraordinarily rude to delete questions after receiving helpful answers that have solved the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65894707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trace your picture in an SVG editor like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Install Inkscape, import your picture, then use the Line or Node tools to trace the outline with as few points as possible.
Then save the SVG and look inside for the path.

Here is the path I ended up with, after simplification:
`M 0,0 V 66 H 13 V 37 H 40 V 66 H 53 V 0 H 40 V 26 H 13 V 0 Z`

And here is your example code with the updated path:

```js
// Get a reference to the <path>
var path = document.querySelector('#star-path');

// Get length of path... ~577px in this case
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

// Make very long dashes (the length of the path itself)
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;

// Offset the dashes so the it appears hidden entirely
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

// Jake Archibald says so
// https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
path.getBoundingClientRect();

// When the page scrolls...
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
 
  // What % down is it? 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript/2387222#2387222
  // Had to try three or four differnet methods here. Kind of a cross-browser nightmare.
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    
  // Length to offset the dashes
  var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
  
  // Draw in reverse
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    
  // When complete, remove the dash array, otherwise shape isn't quite sharp
 // Accounts for fuzzy math
  if (scrollPercentage >= 0.99) {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "none";
    
  } else {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  /* feel free to change height */
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    orange,
    darkblue
  );
}

h1 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

#star-svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}



Resources
```

```html
<h1>Scroll-to-draw</h1>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 250" id="star-svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="star-path" d="M 0,0 V 66 H 13 V 37 H 40 V 66 H 53 V 0 H 40 V 26 H 13 V 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```